# Dolphin, System Settings, Konsole and KSysGuard icons missing in Kubuntu 20.04 (KDE)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons

Title. I can't recall when this problem first occurred. Both icons in Task Manager and Start Menu, as well as the icons inside the apps themselves simply don't appear. The apps work, however the icons are just blank.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Did you change your icon theme or the like?

Comment: @Bruni oh my god, I am so dumb. Thank you so much, apparently I was using a ghost Icon Pack which I have no idea how it got there, but I changed back to Breeze Dark and it's all back. How do I mark this question as solved? I never asked questions on this site until today.

Comment: You just accept, the answer that solves your problem. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably have selected an icon pack that has not the required icons.